# How to pass children to a class nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How do I pass children to this class?

```
export default class MyLayout extends App {
  state = {
    somestate: false,
    anotherstate: true,
  };

  togglestate = (somestate) => {
    this.setState({ somestate });
  };

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        //INSERT CHILDREN HERE
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I will using this as a function component in _app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it should be done:

```
export default class MyLayout extends App {
  state = {
    somestate: false,
    anotherstate: true,
  };

  togglestate = (somestate) => {
    this.setState({ somestate });
  };

  render() {
    const {children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to do this [https://i.imgur.com/zIAyFFz.png]

Comment: @Sanji - I've updated my answer - please approve if this answers your question.